# Single implementation with caller-defined error handling strategy

Tags: c#, error-handling

I want to implement a complex operation with several different strategies for handling errors. Let's say for simplicity's sake that the operation is a bulk file deletion.
In the case where there is an error deleting a file, there's a few things I might want to do in response:

- Immediately exit, and don't delete any more files
- Log the failure and continue deleting the other files
- Add the failure to some collection of failed deletions and continue, and return the collection when the operations are finished

This seems poorly suited to exceptions and try-catch, as it forces me to decide on the strategy upfront, meaning I'd have a different version of the core implementation for each strategy.

Example using exceptions:

```
// Quitting strategy
void DeleteAllQuitting(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
        file.Delete();
    }
}

// Logging strategy
void DeleteAllLogging(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, ILogger log) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
        try {
            file.Delete();
            log.Info(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.Warn(file, e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            log.Warn(file, e);
        }
    }
}

// Collecting strategy
Failure[] DeleteAllCollecting(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files) {
    return files.Select(file => {
        try {
            file.Delete();
            return new Success(file, e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new Failure(file, e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            return new Failure(file, e);
        }
    }).OfType<Failure>().ToArray();
}
```

These all have the same core logic (calling `file.Delete()` on each element) and only differ in how the exceptions from that core operation are handled.
Each new strategy needs a full new implementation.
Of course, in this case the repetition is minimal, but hopefully you can imagine more complex operations wherein the repetition would be quite significant (e.g. recursively deleting directories).

The best thing I could think of was to use generators, lazily yielding the results as the operations fail or succeed, allowing the caller to abort, resume, log, collect, or any other possible strategy with only one core implementation.
But I haven't encountered anything like this in the C# standard library, so I get the impression that this is not idiomatic and maybe there's a better way that I've missed.

Example using generators:

```
// Core implementation
IEnumerable<Result> DeleteAll(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
        Result result;
        try {
            file.Delete();
            result = new Success(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = new Failure(file, e);
        }
        yield return result;
    }
}

// Quitting strategy
void DeleteAllQuitting(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files) {
    foreach (var fail in DeleteAll(files).OfType<Failure>()) {
        throw fail.exception;
    }
}

// Logging strategy
void DeleteAllLogging(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, ILogger log) {
    foreach (var result in DeleteAll(files)) {
    switch (result){
        case Failure f:
            var e = f.exception;
            if (e is IOException || e is SecurityException) {
                log.Warn(f.file, e);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
            break;
        case Success s:
            log.Info(s.file);
            break;
    }
}

// Collecting strategy
Failure[] DeleteAllCollecting(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files) {
    return DeleteAll(files)
        .OfType<Failure>()
        .Where(fail => fail.exception is IOException || fail.exception is SecurityException)
        .ToArray();
}
```

As an alternative, I have also considered making an interface providing OnFail and OnSuccess methods, which would be passed in to the DeleteAll method.
The downside there is, it would require the implementor to define their own class (which I don't think can be nested alongside code as I have done), and it would invert the control flow, so what could have been local control-flow in the caller instead needs to be a hand-written state machine in the handler class.

```
// Core implementation
void DeleteAll(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, IErrorStrategy handler) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
        Exception ex = null;
        try {
            file.Delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ex = e;
        }
        if (ex is null) {
            handler.success(file);
        } else {
            handler.fail(file, ex);
        }
    }
}

// Quitting strategy
void DeleteAllQuitting(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files) {
    class Thrower : IErrorStrategy {
        void fail(FileInfo _, Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    DeleteAll(files, new Thrower());
}

// Logging strategy
void DeleteAllLogging(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, ILogger log) {
    class Logger : IErrorStrategy {
        void success(FileInfo file) {
            log.Info(file, e);
        }
        void fail(FileInfo file, Exception e) {
            if (e is IOException | e is SecurityException) {
                log.Warn(file, e);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    DeleteAll(files, new Logger());
}

// Collecting strategy
Failure[] DeleteAllCollecting(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files) {
    class Collector : IErrorStrategy {
        List<Exception> errors;
        
        void fail(FileInfo file, Exception e) {
            if (e is IOException | e is SecurityException) {
                errors.Add(e)
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    var collector = new Collector();
    DeleteAll(files, collector);
    return collector.errors;
}
```

Please excuse the rambling question, but I suppose the core of it is: Is there a design I've missed that does it better? Or is the generator solution the best we've got?

### Addendum:

On the topic of what I called "inverted control-flow",
it is unlikely to come up in a situation like I've described above,
but the concept is that arbitrary code that produces or consumes a sequence of values can be expressed as either an internal or external iterator.

- An external iterator is characterised by pulling from the sequence (I repeatedly call `it.next()` on the iterator - though in C# this is split into `it.Current` and `it.MoveNext()` on enumerators).
- An internal iterator is characterised by having each item pushed to it in turn (my `with_next(Item)` method is called repeatedly).

One can be considered an inversion of the other, in that an arbitrary external iterator can theoretically be transformed to an equivalent internal iterator, and vice versa.

When the former can be expressed as procedural code, the latter is expressed as a state machine, in order to "remember" where it is in the control-flow.
(I understand C# generator methods (i.e. methods that `yield return`) are actually compiled to a state machine for the same reason)

In most cases of a simple for-loop, they look basically the same:
As an external iterator:

```
for (var item in iter) {
    do_something(item);
}
// compiles to something like
while (iter.has_next()) {
    do_something(it.next());
}
```

As an internal iterator:

```
iter.ForEach(new Foo());

class Foo {
    void with_next(Item item) {
        do_something(item);
    }
}
```

But with arbitrary logic, it can get more complicated. I've provided a rather pathological example below, but with my primary goal being freedom to the caller, this should be a valid strategy.
As an external iterator:

```
if (a(it.next())) {
    b(it.next());
    c(it.next());
} else {
    d(it.next());
}
```

As an internal iterator: (please excuse this as I am not used to hand-writing state machines in C#)

```
try {
    iter.ForEach(new Foo());
} catch Done; // exit early if the state machine asks to

enum Step {
    Test,
    Pass1,
    Pass2,
    Fail1,
    End,
}
class Foo {
    Step current_step = Step.Test;

    void with_next(Item item) {
        switch (current_step) {
            case Step.Test: 
                current_step = a(item) ? Step.Pass1 : Step.Fail1;
                break;
            case Step.Pass1:
                b(item);
                current_step = Step.Pass2;
                break;
            case Step.Pass2:
                c(item);
                current_step = Step.End;
                break;
            case Step.Fail1:
                d(item);
                current_step = Step.End;
                break;
            case Step.End:
                throw new Done());
        }
    }
}
```

Bringing this back to the problem outlined above:

- The version that provides an `IErrorHandler` corresponds strictly to internal iteration: the methods on the handler correspond roughly to specialised `with_next` in the internal iterator.
- The version that iterates over the lazy Results is actually free to use external or internal iteration. The Collecting variant does use internal iteration via LINQ, and the others use external iteration via the `foreach` loop.

Comment: What's wrong with "require the implementor to define their own class"? You could also just use a delegate type, like `Action<FileInfo, Exception>`. The callers' code can use lambdas and be less verbose. Also, what do you mean by "invert the control flow"? What do you think the control flow should look like?

Comment: As @Sweeper says, why are you objecting to the caller defining the exception strategy.

However, there a couple of other options:  
* Return a Success/Fail object that allows the user to decide what to do after the fact.
* Create a custom Exception that gathers all the files and their exceptions, then is thrown after all the files are processed, with the included exception collection.

Thing is, this all depends on who you want to control the exception handling.  If it's internal to the class, you have to define it beforehand.  If it's defined outside, you have to pass it in, or catch.

Comment: My response to Sweeper's comment may take a while. I can answer the second comment now: Both options you provided seem like they are limited to one or the other of always doing as much work before letting the caller intervene, or always cancelling as soon as there is an issue, but no way for the caller to decide between them. And to answer the last part of your comment: I want the caller to have the most control over the handling strategy. I've shown the different strategies as methods alongside the core method simply because it is convenient, but this could be in user code.

Comment: Isn't taking a decision not already a user intervention?

Comment: On another note: have you been looking into Polly and if not use it, maybe look at how they do it?

Comment: @Sweeper regarding the first 2 parts of your question: Requiring a class means needing a bespoke class for what could otherwise be a fairly straightforward method body, and I don't think the method-local class definition I've written is actually legal. My examples only showed the strategy using the error case, in which case a single delegate would suffice, but in general, I'd want a strategy to be able to respond to both successes and failures. I've updated the Logging handler to include logging on the success case.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify what I mean by "Control-flow inversion", in an addendum to the question.

Comment: @Fildor I've not heard of Polly - it certainly seems to be in a related space, but I'm not sure if I can use it for my problem. I'll check it out though.